# Can't resume from suspend. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: arch-linux, acpi

I'm using Arch linux. If I execute `systemctl suspend` from any tty I can resume without any issue. While using i3, `systemctl suspend` is causing problem while resuming. I get a message saying  `do_IRQ: 0.55 No irq handler for vector` and I can't switch to other tty either.
I tried adding `acpi= noirq` to Grub which fixed this issue but caused another major problem(Touchpad and keyboard not all working). What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got a work around accidentally. It's seems it has something to do with `graphical.target` .
I thought about trying dwm and Xfce. Then I installed `lightdm` so that I can switch between WMs easily. Now, the computer doesn't get stuck while resuming from suspend.
I doubt when I used startx I used bare `.xinitrc`. But when I used lightdm , it started some essential systemd services. This answer doesn't seem to be complete. Someone please enlighten me about what might have caused this problem.